# External drive has strange files "_*" appearing - culprit is maybe rsync or SMB access?

Tags: external-hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, rsync

I'm using rsync to back up folders from my iMac to a WD MyBook and the process seems to leave files such as these:

```
_0O1MN~H.MP4  
_2C0X2~3.AVI  
_ALLYW~B.SRT  
_VUC69~7
```

The last one is the most common, finding one in each folder at times. The others (shadows of other files judging by the extensions) not so common but when I find them there are multiples in the same folder. A one off so to speak.

I read somewhere some time back, but can't find it, that it may actually have something to do with the mode I am accessing the MyBook with. eg. SMB rather than .. and here's where my recall fails me.

EDIT: ok I've found the other means of access, particular to OSX it seems:
[AFP - Apple Filing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol%E2%80%8E/)

EDIT: they also seem to defy deletion, in some cases.  but on discovering the AFP access I think that might be the access that allows me to delete them (with less messing around).

ok, I couldn't find at first because I had been deleting them,manually  so I was in the process of doing another rsync to see if I could reproduce; I noticed in the file build list (for a dry run) that I had one on the local HDD!

"Get info" tells me it's a "**Unix Executable**".
The file was in a hidden ".AppleDouble" folder. When I put that to the "file <>" test you asked for it told me:

```
 _VUC69~7: AppleDouble encoded Macintosh file.
```

(ps. am I able to do linefeeds in comments as I'm struggling to do it O_o)

Comment: You're sure it's `_`, not `._` (starting with a period)?

Comment: no, they aren't dot files. I've read here about making an exclude file for rsync, sorry I digress, but just prefixed with '_'.  Thanks for the edit, was that done just with TAB or spaces before those lines?

Comment: 4 spaces make it mono spaced

Comment: Can you establish the type of the extension-less files? A command like "file _VUC69~" will do it.

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae. Edited my post to reflect new info.

Comment: And thanks to @CanadianLuke also. Interesting markup lingo on here, I like but of course I'm still fumbling my way at this point.